# Angular doesn't remove colon (:) before route

Tags: angular, routes

I've been following the official Angular 4 Hero tutorial in my own version where I am displaying a list of students and a click on a student should show detailed information.
I've come to the point where I need to do the routes for each component and have encountered an issue that I couldn't resolve, it worked just fine before setting up routes.

Basically, the problem is that the application route for StudentDetailsComponent doesn't work. I've compared it to the tutorial and noticed that in my URL, the colon (:) is not removed before the student index.

Example: localhost:4200/details/:140021 whereas in the tutorial it is removed such as localhost:4200/details/23

I am pretty sure the rest of the code is correct, I just can't seem to find the reason why this route doesn't work.

This is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/list', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'list', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'details/:index', component: StudentDetailsComponent },
];
```

This is how I get the index in student-details.component.ts:

```
getStudent(): void {
   const index = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('index');
   this.studentManagementService.getStudent(index).subscribe(student => 
   this.student = student);
}
```

This is how I get the actual selected student in student-management.service.ts:

```
getStudent(index: number): Observable<Student>{
  return of(STUDENTS.find(student => student.index === index));
}
```

And this is how I display the list of students from which you should be able to click on a student and get the details:

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let student of students">
      <a routerLink="/details/:{{student.index}}">
        {{student.firstName}} {{student.lastName}}
      </a>
</li>
```

The entire code can be found on [GitHub, branch: routing](https://github.com/fidanym/VP_LabProject/tree/routing/src/app).

I literally have no idea where to look for the error as I'm rather new to Angular but I also have spent a lot of time trying to find what I'm doing wrong. Comparing to the tutorial project which I also did from start to finish, everything is as it should be.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your routerLink.

Change it to :

```
<a [routerLink]="['/details', student.index]">
```

Comment: Thank you, this did work although now it only works the first time I click on a student, after that it doesn't change even though the URL changes accordingly to the index that is selected.

I do not know why the example that is used in the Angular Heroes tutorial doesn't work in my case because it is basically the same thing.